# isolating data in MATlab

Tags: matlab

I am trying to isolate specific sections of data in a `m x 4` matrix. There are tons of data points and I need to be able to isolate specific sections of the data in the matrix.

To add to the problem I have 8 data sets that are identical in size (`m x 8`), each with different data values in them. Further, in each matrix of data, there is a break where there are 2 columns instead of 4.

I need to figure out a way to read all the files in at once, isolate specific columns of the data in all 8 matrices, isolate the same section of data in all 8 matrices and then average the data into a single matrix.

right now what I have is:

```
clear
for n = 1:8
    raw = fileread(['filename',num2str(n)]); %num2str(n) is the test number which goes from 1-8
end
```

*Is there a shorter way to do this?*

The data looks like this:

```
  1000 50
  1 0.01 33.37 252.052
  2 0.03 24.43 302.95
  3 0.05 113.4 303.35
  4 0.07 36.93 301.36
  5 0.09 30.18 272.923
  6 0.11 21.73 311.392
  7 0.13 98.14 309.547
  8 0.15 57.99 307.23
  9 0.17 28.3 294.802
  10 0.19 25.87 315.202
  11 0.21 88.8 271.713
  12 0.23 65.62 286.422
  13 0.25 27.9 338.652
  14 0.27 27.5 323.503
  15 0.29 65.8 302.545
  16 0.31 85.68 288.909
  17 0.33 25.68 368.932
  18 0.35 28.1 372.731
  19 0.37 52.03 386.33
  20 0.39 104.95 402.87
  21 0.41 23.45 349.083
  22 0.43 30.31 353.418
  23 0.45 42.89 410.256
  24 0.47 109.12 421.674
  25 0.49 23.26 379.214
  26 0.51 35.76 343.582
  27 0.53 26.3 401.289
  28 0.55 118.04 434.815
  29 0.57 29.12 376.607
  30 0.59 33.58 424.887
  31 0.61 23.23 393.065
  32 0.63 107.01 394.063
  33 0.65 47.05 449.556
  34 0.67 25.2 347.347
  35 0.69 29.56 386.667
  36 0.71 93.81 310.077
  37 0.73 59.56 338.902
  38 0.75 26.5 257.647
  39 0.77 25.89 296.728
  40 0.79 75.37 284.466
  41 0.81 78.66 274.047
  42 0.83 28.25 263.322
  43 0.85 24.87 249.153
  44 0.87 58.41 294.226
  45 0.89 97.23 288.702
  46 0.91 22.02 313.901
  47 0.93 30.99 278.787
  48 0.95 37.59 331.611
  49 0.97 116.68 291.19
  50 0.99 21.89 277.714
  2000 50
  1 0.01 32.46 254.776
  2 0.03 23.79 323.679
  3 0.05 112.33 301.529
  4 0.07 37.24 318.256
  5 0.09 30.47 254.25
  6 0.11 23.79 307.803
  7 0.13 100.33 317.979
  8 0.15 54.73 308.255
  9 0.17 27.95 268.967
  10 0.19 26.2 314.853
  11 0.21 87.03 271.006
  12 0.23 66.81 289.273
  13 0.25 27.41 317.178
  14 0.27 27.33 321.76
  15 0.29 69.99 325.501
  16 0.31 82.7 287.062
  17 0.33 26.21 393.801
  18 0.35 28.07 373.959
  19 0.37 57.72 384.509
  20 0.39 99.11 395.208
  21 0.41 22.67 352.55
  22 0.43 30.84 363.797
  23 0.45 43.4 413.233
  24 0.47 108.33 420.134
  25 0.49 23.17 402.015
  26 0.51 36.52 340.785
  27 0.53 26.55 374.52
  28 0.55 120.69 422.856
  29 0.57 26.18 392.931
  30 0.59 33.7 428.731
  31 0.61 22.82 412.042
  32 0.63 105.36 407.581
  33 0.65 48.39 426.492
  34 0.67 26.35 356.509
  35 0.69 27.29 389.012
  36 0.71 90.77 303.742
  37 0.73 62.94 324.713
  38 0.75 27.02 273.747
  39 0.77 27.18 264.457
  40 0.79 71.91 293.905
  41 0.81 78.46 274.991
  42 0.83 28.82 272.619
  43 0.85 27.21 241.423
  44 0.87 54.81 285.661
  45 0.89 101.26 292.041
  46 0.91 22.54 317.539
  47 0.93 30.44 292.688
  48 0.95 39.77 326.761
  49 0.97 115.9 285.359
  50 0.99 21.04 296.302
```

the first column repeats after completing a 1-50 cycle and the second column repeats every 0.01-0.99
I'm trying to isolate the data in each cycle and make it equal to a single variable that I can manipulate or graph.

Comment: We need more details, what does the data look like? What is the specific case that you want to isolate?

Comment: 46 0.91 26.74 338.587
  47 0.93 59.92 334.635
  48 0.95 92.95 310.797
  49 0.97 24.15 275.747
  50 0.99 31.34 298.097
250000 50
  1 0.01 39.21 306.325
  2 0.03 112.6 290.669
  3 0.05 22.46 259.802
  4 0.07 30.6 342.462

Comment: Use the edit button and add it to the question. Format it correctly by adding 4 spaces in front like i have done with your code. Also what is the specific case you want to isolate? Again, add it to the question.

Comment: Does that look better?

Comment: H?ave you looked at this:  http://www.mathworks.com.au/matlabcentral/answers/54068-how-to-read-data-file-with-rows-of-different-length

Comment: That is helpful, but if you look at the small section of data I put into the question, you'll see that the data starts out as a 1 x 2 matrix, then right after goes 1 x 4, and then after 50 points of data it has one more line that is 1 x 2. The cycle then repeats. I just want the data in between the 1 x 2 lines.

Answer (score 0):

So you can use the answer provided [here](http://www.mathworks.com.au/matlabcentral/answers/54068-how-to-read-data-file-with-rows-of-different-length) to transform your data into a cell array. ie:

```
[1000] [50]   []      []
[1]    [0.01] [33.37] [252.052]
...
[50]   [0.99] [21.89] [277.714]
[2000] [50]   []      []
[1]    [0.01] [32.46] [254.776]
```

You can then search for the rows that have two empty cells.

```
emptyCells = cellfun(@isempty,a);
```

You should be able to then seperate your data this way. Say you find that between row 51 and 101 are where your numbers lie. You can convert them into a matrix using:

```
matrix = cell2mat(cell(51:101, :))
```

Comment: what if I want to skip the first three lines? The first three lines in my data file I need to skip.

Comment: If it is always 3 lines you can just do `fgets(fid)` at the start 3 times and it will skip the first 3 lines.

Comment: Is there a way I can create a for loop that will find the blocks of data for me and then isolate them in separate matrices? Or even just take data every 50 data points